# Cascade application of merging member function on vector of vectors with constraint

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

I have the following vector of vectors:

```
V = std::vector<std::vector<MyType> >
```

The vectors contained in V are not necessarily of the same length. MyType has a member function merge with the following signature:

```
bool MyType::merge(MyType in, MyType &out);
```

This member function takes self and in and checks if they can be merged into out. If so, out is set to the merged result and the
function returns true. Otherwise false is returned and out is not modified.

I want to go through each vector in V and get all possible combined merges into a final result std::vector. As an example,
if V contains three vectors A, B, C with 3 elements each, I want to get a vector with the following result:

```
A_0 - B_0 - C_0
A_0 - B_0 _ C_1
A_0 - B_0 _ C_2
A_0 - B_1 - C_0
A_0 - B_1 _ C_1
A_0 - B_1 _ C_2
A_0 - B_2 - C_0
A_0 - B_2 _ C_1
A_0 - B_2 _ C_2
A_1 - B_0 ... etc
```

The merged result should *not* be in the result vector if at any point the merge returns false.

The explanation is a bit lengthy but I have the feeling this should not be very difficult, and I have the feeling there is a
simple way of accomplishing this with some stl functionality, but I simply don't see it.

Comment: The example code you provide does not really match the function signature you provided. It takes two argument and returns a bool, while your example code suggests it is a unary `MyType` member function, returning a `MyType` (or something convertible to it).

Comment: Arne, thanks, I changed the example to be more generic instead of actual example code.

Comment: I can't see any "merging" in your example. I can only see counting. Where is function `merge` called? On what input and what output?

Comment: And what does "combined merges" mean? Do you mean that e.g. for line `A_0 - B_1 - C_0` you need something like `X = A_0; X.merge(B_1, Y); Y.merge(C_0, Z);`?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very recursive problem, it is merging the N-dimensional cartesian product of the vectors' elements:

You want to merge each element of A with all outcomes of merging all possible combinations of merging elements from B,C,... and put that into a result vector, i.e. merge the first dimension with the result of the cartesian merge product of the remaining N-1 dimensions. The recursion's end is the last dimension:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<MyType>>::const_iterator vvIter;
std::vector<MyType> cartesianMerge(vvIter start, vvIter end) {

   auto const& currentVector = *start;

   if (start+1 == end) return currentVector; //end recursion

   auto mergeWith = cartesianMerge(start+1, end); //recursie

   std::vector<MyType> results;
   MyType temp;
   for (auto const& lhs : currentVector)
     for (auto const& rhs : mergeWith )
        if (lhs.merge(rhs, temp)) results.push_back(temp);

   return results;
}

int main() {
  auto v = std::vector<std::vector<MyType> >{ /* ... you fill it! ... */ };

  auto allMerged = cartesianMerge(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

This could be maybe generalized using standard algorithms like `std::transform` but since it's a conditinal transformation (no result if the merge fails), it would not look much clearer.